# Perl SOAP::Lite not setting cookes

Tags: perl, cookies, soap

I'm trying to use SOAP::Lite to interact with the Zimbra SOAP interface.  Apparently, for admin functions, it needs an auth token sent as a cookie.  When I use the documented form (apparently inherited from LWP::UserAgent), it's not working:

```
...
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => \&log_requests ];
...
my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new(ignore_discard => 1, ZM_ADMIN_AUTH_TOKEN => $auth_token);
$soap->transport->cookie_jar($cookies);

my $som = $soap->call('NoOpRequest',
                        SOAP::Data->name('authToken')->value($auth_token),
                    );

print Dumper($som->result);
...
sub log_requests {
    open LOGFILE,">request.log";
    print LOGFILE Dumper(@_);
    close LOGFILE;
}
```

The relevant part of the request log is the headers in the request, which don't contain any cookies (and Zimbra is complaining about no auth token):

```
'_headers' => bless( {
               'user-agent' => 'SOAP::Lite/Perl/1.27',
               'soapaction' => '"urn:zimbraAdmin#NoOpRequest"',
               'content-type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
               'accept' => [
                     'text/xml',
                     'multipart/*',
                     'application/soap'
                   ],
               'content-length' => 827
             }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
```

Comment: You never set any cookies. You pass an unrecognized option `ZM_ADMIN_AUTH_TOKEN`. Use `$cookies->set_cookie`

Answer (score 0):

ikegami's comment was the right answer (needed to call set_cookie, not pass the cookie as an argument to setting up the cookie jar), however the documentation on set_cookie() is ... incomplete; here are the notes I made after looking at the source to figure out what was needed to get the cookie to actually get set:

```
#
# $cookie_jar->set_cookie( $version, $key, $val, $path, $domain, $port, $path_spec, $secure, $maxage, $discard, \%rest )
# $version should be 0
# $key, $val, $path must be set
# $key must not start with $
# $path must start with /
# $port should be undef
# $maxage must be > 0
#
$cookies->set_cookie(0, 'ZM_ADMIN_AUTH_TOKEN', $admin_token, '/', 'zmail-admin.peak.org', undef, 1, 86400, 1);
```